# Why isn't my thread running the way it is supposed to?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am reading content from file and displaying it to GUI.

Here is my file:

```
Log ; ytr
Thread Sleep ; 654
Log ; hgfd
Thread Sleep ; 543
Log ; hgfd
Thread Sleep ; 7654
Log ; grdr
```

I select a file and it reads the file and then updates the GUI simultaneously. So there is a button which lets me choose my file. The above is a sample of one of my file and I read that and if its "Log" is outputs whatever it is to the GUI.

I am doing my multithreading at the `log` function

UPDATE here is my entire (relevant) code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    final static TextArea m_text_area = new TextArea();
final static GridPane m_grid = new GridPane();
final FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
static String parameters = "";
final static Scene m_scene = new Scene(m_grid, 500, 500);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Choose your file...");

    m_grid.add(m_text_area, 0, 1);
    m_grid.add(btn, 0, 0);

    final String thread_sleep = "Thread Sleep";
    final String log = "Log";

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            List<File> list = fileChooser
                    .showOpenMultipleDialog(primaryStage);
            if (list != null) {
                for (File file : list) {

                    if (file.isFile()) {

                        if (file.getName().indexOf(".") != 0) {

                            BufferedReader br = null;

                            try {

                                String sCurrentLine;

                                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file
                                        .getAbsolutePath().toString()));

                                int i = 0;
                                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                                    if (!sCurrentLine.startsWith("#")) {

                                        String line[] = sCurrentLine
                                                .split(";");

                                        String command = line[0].trim();

                                        try {
                                            parameters = line[1].trim();
                                        } catch (Exception e5) {

                                        }

                                        switch (command) {

                                        case thread_sleep: {

                                                Thread.sleep(Integer
                                                        .parseInt(parameters));
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        case log: {

                                            log(parameters);
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            } catch (IOException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    if (br != null)
                                        br.close();
                                } catch (IOException ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(m_scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void log(String text) {

    final String textToDisplay = text;
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_text_area.appendText(textToDisplay + "\n");

        }
    });

    }
}
```

**My issue: The GUI freezes and updates only one the whole program has been executed**

Comment: Show us the whole code. Can't debug anything with that

Comment: Not enough code here to say for sure what is going on.  Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You forgot the break in the first case statement, so it continues with the second case which is trying to parse a non-integer in Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. Ill just quickly give the relevant code.

Comment: May also need to do `split[0].trim()` as the `split(";")` will not remove the spaces.

Comment: Just a second! Im updating my code and I already did trim() thanks :) Im trying to format it and post it

Comment: Also - creating a new `Runnable` for every line you want to log is not a good idea. You would be better off using a `BlockingQueue<String>` as a communications link between two threads.

Comment: Okay, let me have a look at it! :)

Comment: ...does my code make sense?  ,_,

Comment: I don’t see any multi-threading. So it’s clear that your single thread can’t do two things, processing your file and updating your UI, at the same time.

Comment: I did multithreading in the `log` function! I created a new runnable each and every single time

Comment: There's no multithreading in your `log` method. Creating a `Runnable` does not create new `Thread`s. Everything is happening on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: Oh! But I've been using the same log method for another GUI and it works the way I want there? :/

Answer (score 0):

You are `sleep`ing inside the event. The GUI cannot process further events until the current event finishes. That is why the program freezes.

You need to use a background worker thread for this. There is a tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        // long-running task
        return (Void)null;
   }
};

new Thread(task).start();
```